# Using EaselJS, my spritesheet-based map is not showing up

Tags: javascript, tilemap, easeljs

I have a random map that generates based on a level and a set of Tile ID's, constructed using a Height Map generator I wrote using the BitmapData extension.

I've confirmed that the Tile IDs are generated correctly and can be modified to cycle through a set of tiles and changing circumstances.

The actual base image that holds the tiles is loaded and I was able to draw 
it separately.

However... after I update the stage when the function finishes building, I don't see any map at all and I don't understand why. I've tried to add to a container and to the stage directly, neither method is working.

Could anyone identify the problem?

```
function buildBackground()
{
    var mapSeed = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

    var channel = Object.create(createjs.BitmapDataChannel);
    var channelOptions = channel.RED | channel.GREEN | channel.BLUE;

    var offsets = [new createjs.Point(0, 0), new createjs.Point(0, 0)];
    var interpolateType = "cos";

    var TileMap = new Array();

    accessMap = new createjs.BitmapData(null, 200, 200);
    accessMap.perlinNoise(100, 100, 6, mapSeed, true, false, channelOptions, true, offsets, interpolateType);

    var BitmapLayout = new createjs.Bitmap(accessMap.canvas);

    BitmapLayout.scaleX = 5;
    BitmapLayout.scaleY = 4;

    BitmapLayout.x = 0;
    BitmapLayout.y = 0;

    var gridSizeX = 10;
    var gridSizeY = 7;

    heightMap = new Array();

    for (x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
    {
        heightMap[x] = new Array();
        for (y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
        {
            heightMap[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }


var pixelPoint = new createjs.Point();
var darkest_pixel = 1;
var brightest_pixel = 0;

for (x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
    {
        pixelPoint.x = Math.round((x/gridSizeX) * accessMap.width) + 1; 
        pixelPoint.y = Math.round((y/gridSizeY) * accessMap.height) + 1;

        heightMap[x][y] = accessMap.getPixel(pixelPoint.x, pixelPoint.y);

        heightMap[x][y] /= 0xffffff;

        if (heightMap[x][y] < darkest_pixel) {
            darkest_pixel = heightMap[x][y];
        }

        heightMap[x][y] = Math.round(heightMap[x][y] * (Math.random() * 3));
    }
}

for (x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
{
    TileMap[x] = new Array();
    for (y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
    {
        TileMap[x][y] = 0;
        TileMap[x][y] = Math.round(heightMap[x][y] * (Math.random() * 5));
    }
}



var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(preload.getResult("BackgroundTiles"));

var BackgroundTileObjData = {
    images: [bitmap],
    frames: {width: 100, height: 100}
};

var BackgroundTileInfo = new createjs.SpriteSheet(BackgroundTileObjData);

var frameSize = 100;

var graphic = new createjs.Graphics();


for (x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
    {
        var TileID = TileMap[x][y];

        var levelModifier = 1;
        var tile = new createjs.Sprite(BackgroundTileInfo);
        tile.gotoAndStop(TileID);
        tile.x = 100 * x;
        tile.y = 100 * y;

        stage.addChild(tile);

    }
}

stage.update();
console.log("Tile SpriteSheet?");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the EaselJS documentation states for SpriteSheet objects :

> SpriteSheets are an object with two required properties (images and frames), and two optional properties (framerate and animations). This makes them easy to define in javascript code, or in JSON.
>
> images : An array of source images. Images can be either an **HTMlimage
>   instance, or a uri to an image**. The former is recommended to control
>   preloading.

Instead you pass a createjs.bitmap object which is neither.
So basically if you change your SpriteSheet object to :

```
var BackgroundTileObjData = {
 images: [bitmap.image],
frames: {width: 100, height: 100}};

//or even this should work : 
//images: ['/uri/to/your/tile/image']
```

It should work.